# Can I ask questions related to hardware?

Tags: discussion

I have a question related to my new computer hardware. Would it be okay to ask it on superuser.com?

If the question itself should be described then let me know and I'll edit this post.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Don't worry posting your question to try it out, you can always delete it if it seems wrong until answers have been posted to it. The [FAQ](http://superuser.com) should give a fairly good idea. If still in doubt, feel free to share the question... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you [can ask questions about computer hardware](https://superuser.com/faq#questions).

There are some limitations like no shopping or buying recommendations, read more about in the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq)...

Comment: awesome thanks guys and yes I could have read faqs but didn't wanna get flamed by community :P so was making sure